# How to initialise a class and a shape property within it?

Tags: java, javafx, simulation

I am building a map, and on it, I'm trying to add nodes such as walls, cameras, doors, etc... now these are all composed of shapes such as rectangles, I've done this already but I'm trying to rework it as I'm having trouble with my collision detection algorithm, as I can check collision between shapes but it causes me problems when I try to tell the class from which the shape has derived from (e.g., rectangle for door or wall) what actions to take.

```
public class Door {

    private int x, y;

    public Door(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public Door getTarget() {
        Door door = new Rectangle(x, y, 30, 20);
        return door;
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can get this sort of class to work and return me a rectangle without having to use the getTarget() method?

```
public class Door extends Rectangle {

    public double x,y;
    public Rectangle door;

    public Door(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        door = new Rectangle(x, y, 30, 20);
    }

}
```

Comment: Confused.... "return me a rectangle without having to use the getTarget() method".... So you want a way of getting something from an object without calling a method... ? Why is calling a method bad? You could just add a getter for getTarget() that just returns this.door?

Comment: So I have a collision detection algorithm in the main class of my program, now the algorithm takes a Shape array as a parameter (this array contains all nodes shapes; such as rectangles for all the doors, I have humans in the program as well which use circles for example) so let's say a human (circle) collides with a door (rectangle), I then want to call a function in the human class to change his walking direction, however since I only parsed the shapes to the algorithm I don't know how to tell the human class itself to change direction, I can only instruct the shape to make an action.

Comment: I feel like theres a really simple solution here but i'm blind to it...

Comment: What exactly is the `Door` class responsible for? Should it be the node displayed? Should it somehow manage the displayed nodes? Why does the second version both extend `Rectangle` and contain a `Rectangle` field  named `door` (Is your door made of more doors???)? Something else? Also `Door door = new Rectangle(x, y, 30, 20);` will not work unless you're using a custom `Rectangle` class that ***extends*** `Door`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need a `Rectangle` field in your `Door` class, you `Door` already extends `Rectangle`. By saying that `Door` extends `Rectangle`, it means that `Door` IS a `Rectangle`. So if you had a collision checking function like so:

```
public Boolean testCollision(Rectangle first, Rectangle second) { ... }
```

You could simply pass any `Door` object to this method.

```
Door first = new Door()
Door second = new Door()
if (testCollision(first, second) { 
    // do stuff 
}
```

If you need to distinguish between different `Rectangle` types in your `testCollision` method, you can cast:

```
if (first instanceof Door) {
    Door firstAsDoor = (Door)first;
}
```